# ETag option not visualized correctly on the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, coap

I'm using the library node-coap, and I have coded a simple coap client, that send get request to a local coap server, in particular the PlugTest server of the californium framework, this is the code of the client:

```
var req = {
    hostname:"localhost",
    method:"GET",
    pathname:"validate"
}
var coapReq = coap.request(req)
coapReq.end()
coapReq.on('response',function(res){
    console.log('------------Response--------------')
    console.log("Status Code:"+res.code)
    res.options.forEach(function(item){
        console.log('Option Name:'+item.name+' value:'+item.value)
    })
    console.log("Body:"+res.payload)
})
```

On the console I get this output:

```
> Status Code:2.05 Option Name:ETag value:�� Option Name:Content-Format
> value:text/plain Body:Type: 0 (CON) Code: 1 (GET) MID: 29451 Token:
> cf1a7acd
```

Can someone tell me why the ETag options isn't visualized correctly?

Comment: Because it contains extended characters which your console can't display.

Comment: I think that they are binary data, how I can display it correctly, for example like 0x0712 ?

Comment: One option is to hex encode the value.